# run programs from select menu

Tags: bash, scripts, metasploit

I've created a simple bash script to create a select menu which look like this :

1) Run nmap
2) Wireshark
3) metasploit framework
4) Exit

now I want to run these programs as per menu selection. I am very new to bash scripting so looking for anyone's help here.

Answer (score 1):

Read reads ina user input to a variable.

```
echo 'Select an option
  1) Run nmap 
  2) Wireshark 
  3) metasploit framework 
  4) Exit?'
read OPTION
```

From here on the $OPION variable is set,  test with

```
if [ "$OPTION" == "1" ]
then
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple example:

1. Select script:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   array=()

   while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]
   do
       if [ ! -z "$line" ]; then
           array+=("$line")
       fi
   done < "$1"

   select fname in "${array[@]}";
   do
       /bin/bash -c "$fname"
       break;
   done
   ```

Script operation:

1. `while loop`: Take commands a create an `array` called `array`, then
2. Read the commands from the array and create a `menu` that you choose from.

Information:

1. `IFS=''` (or `IFS=`) prevents leading/trailing whitespace from being trimmed.
2. `-r` prevents backslash escapes from being interpreted.
3. `|| [[ -n $line ]]` prevents the last line from being ignored if it doesn't end with a `\n` (since read returns a non-zero exit code when it encounters EOF).
4. `[ ! -z "$line" ]` ignore blank lines in the source file.
5. `${array[@]}` array values